# dask dataframe groupby and multi index raises ValueError

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I have the following dataframe

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'_id':['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4'],'http_user':['user1', 'user1', 'user2', 'user2'], 'dst': ['1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '2.2.2.2'], 'dst_port':[80,80,80,80], 'score':[40, 50, 10, 80]})
alerts = dd.from_pandas(dataframe, npartitions=5)
```

Alerts data normally is created from data downloaded by Elasticsearch. 
Then I obtain some data from  2 MySQL tables that are empty

```
alert_status_change = dd.read_sql_table('api_alerts_status_change',
                                                    db_url, index_col='id',
                                                    npartitions=4,
                                                    columns=['status',
                                                             'alert_id',
                                                             'reason_id']).reset_index()

reasons = dd.read_sql_table('api_alerts_reasons', db_url,
                            index_col='id', npartitions=4).reset_index()
```

Until here I can perform the following aggregation successfully:

```
alerts.groupby(['http_user', 'dst', 'dst_port']).score.max().compute()
```

Normally I want to merge alerts and the two dataframes from the db tables and then perform a groupby. The following merges are performed:

```
alerts = alerts.merge(alert_status_change, left_on='_id',
                              right_on='alert_id')
alerts = alerts.merge(reasons, left_on='reason_id',
                              right_on='id')
```

But trying to do the same groupby aggregation gives me the following error:

```
distributed.worker - WARNING -  Compute Failed
Function:  execute_task
args:      ((<built-in function apply>, <function _groupby_aggregate at 0x7f9d28aabb90>, [(<function _concat at 0x7f9d28af0488>, [Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []])], {'levels': [0, 1, 2], 'aggfunc': <methodcaller: max>}))
kwargs:    {}
Exception: ValueError('multiple levels only valid with MultiIndex',)
```

The python stack trace (last lines)

```
/home/avlach/virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in __init__
    514                                                     level=level,
    515                                                     sort=sort,
--> 516                                                     mutated=self.mutated)
    517 
    518         self.obj = obj

/home/avlach/virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in _get_grouper()
   2830                     raise ValueError('No group keys passed!')
   2831                 else:
-> 2832                     raise ValueError('multiple levels only valid with '
   2833                                      'MultiIndex')
   2834 

ValueError: multiple levels only valid with MultiIndex
```

When perfroming groupby and checking the `_meta.index` attribute I get:

```
>> alerts.groupby(['http_user', 'dst', 'dst_port']).score.max()._meta.index
>> Index([], dtype='object')
```

Manually setting that to a MultiIndex has no effect:

```
max_score = alerts.groupby(
            ['http_user', 'dst', 'dst_port']).score.max()
max_score._meta.index = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[], [], []], labels=[[], [], []], names=['http_user', 'dst', 'dst_port'])

max_score._meta.index
MultiIndex(levels=[[], [], []],
       labels=[[], [], []],
       names=[u'http_user', u'dst', u'dst_port'])
```

The code above works when I use a dummy dataframe. But when I get alerts from Elasticsearch then It won't. Where does this error come from?